# Request: rename [dialogflow] to [dialogflow-es] (and related maintenance)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Google recently renamed the [Dialogflow](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs) product to Dialogflow ES and released a new product that is almost completely incompatible named Dialogflow CX.

In order to reduce confusion, I propose:

- Renaming the [dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow) tag to [dialogflow-es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow-es)
- Renaming the [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow-fulfillment) tag to [dialogflow-es-fulfillment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow-es-fulfillment)
- Making [dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow) and [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow-fulfillment) synonyms for their new tag names
- Establishing the [dialogflow-cx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow-cx) tag (which I've done, and moved one question into it already)

Once these are done, I'll update the tag wiki to make each tag clear about its purpose and the specific product it applies to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I renamed both the tags as requested, and added the required synonyms. That is:

[dialogflow-fulfillment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow-fulfillment) → [dialogflow-es-fulfillment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow-es-fulfillment) (× 563)
[dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow) → [dialogflow-es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow-es) (× 4955)

For the tag wikis and excerpts, remember to mention clearly about the usage of each of the tags. There certainly would be a lot of wrongly tagged posts (ES instead of CX, and vice-versa), but that's something which we can't help.